# Why these two nearly the same bit-shift functions produce different answers?

Tags: c++, bit, bit-shift

Using `unsigned` to represent a *mask* for first `len` bits, I wrote a function as below:

```
void left_shift(int len) {
  unsigned x = ~0u << (32 - len);
  printf("%08x\n", x);
}
```

However, when I call `left_shift(0)` the console prints `ffffffff`, rather than `00000000` that I expected.

So, I made another function to test whether I was misunderstanding the bit-shift operation as below:

```
void left_shift() {
  unsigned x = ~0u << (32 - 0);
  printf("%08x\n", x);
}
```

This time, it prints the expected `00000000`.

To conclude:

```
int main() {
  left_shift();   // prints "00000000"
  left_shift(0);  // prints "ffffffff"
  return 0;
}
```

I'm really confusing. Could anyone help explain?

Comment: You're facing undefined behavior, so the compiler is free to produce code that acts that way. By the way, is your question about C or C++, because these are different languages and C standards mandate different behavior here than C++ standards.

Comment: As you cannot overload a function in C, I removed the C tag.

Comment: Compiler says, `warning: left shift count >= width of type`. That should have been a hint.

Comment: [another compiler prints zeros both times](http://ideone.com/LfJgkg)